# Getting 'float' object has no attribute 'encode' while sending email from python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boto3

I am getting an error 'float' object has no attribute 'encode' while I am sending email from python.
This was running successfully was past 6-7 days without any issues.

```
def create_message(send_from, send_to, cc_to, subject, plain_text_body):
    
    message = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    message['From'] = send_from
    
    message['To'] =send_to    
    message['Cc'] = cc_to
    message['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    message['Subject'] = subject
    message.attach(MIMEText(plain_text_body, 'plain'))
    return message

def add_attachment_from_local_disk(message, path):
    with open(path, "rb") as file:
        part = MIMEApplication(file.read(),Name=basename(path))
        part['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % basename(path)
        message.attach(part)
        
def send_message(message):
    print(message)
    client = boto3.client("ses",region_name='eu-west-1')
    response = client.send_raw_email(RawMessage = {"Data": message.as_string()})

for i, row in final_email.iterrows():
    subject  = row["Subject"]
    to_address = row['fba_to__notifications'] or row['lsp_escalation_back_up'] or "no_address@rs-components.com"
    cc_list =   row['cc_list']
    send_from="ukrd@kuedid.com"
    message = create_message(send_from,to_address, cc_list, subject, plain_text_body=body)
    send_message(message)
```

**Error**

```
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\email\_policybase.py in _fold(self, name, value, sanitize)
    367             if self.max_line_length is not None:
    368                 maxlinelen = self.max_line_length
--> 369             parts.append(h.encode(linesep=self.linesep, maxlinelen=maxlinelen))
    370         parts.append(self.linesep)
    371         return ''.join(parts)

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide the outcome of `print(message)`? I guess, something there is a float, instead of `str`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that the library receives a float where it would expect a string. From your code, I would expect that either `body` or one field from `final_email` contains a float.

I would not be surprised for the float to be a NaN because of an empty value in the dataframe. To make sure (or to make your code more robust) you could try to filter the exception and display the offending values:

```
for i, row in final_email.iterrows():
    subject  = row["Subject"]
    to_address = row['fba_to__notifications'] or row['lsp_escalation_back_up'] or "no_address@rs-components.com"
    cc_list =   row['cc_list']
    send_from="ukrd@kuedid.com"
    try:
        message = create_message(send_from,to_address, cc_list, subject, plain_text_body=body)
    except AttributeError as e:
        print('Error composing email', send_from,to_address, cc_list, subject, body, '\n', e)
        # raise # optionaly re-raise the exception if you want to stop processing
    send_message(message)
```

---

Anyway there is another problem here. `NaN` is seen as `True` when converted to a boolean in Python code. So the `to_address` assignation will not fallback to a `or` expression if it is NaN. So you should either `combine_first` the relevant columns if it makes sense (`final_email['fba_to__notifications'].combine_first(final_email['lsp_escalation_back_up'].fillna('no_address@rs-components.com')`), or explicitely test for NaN values:

```
to_address = row['fba_to__notifications'] if not np.isnan(row['fba_to__notifications']) \
    else row['lsp_escalation_back_up'] if not isnan(row['lsp_escalation_back_up']) \
    else "no_address@rs-components.com"
```

Comment: My body is not float. Its breaking when  row['fba_to__notifications'] or row['lsp_escalation_back_up']  when both are `NaN'.Bascially ``to_address = row['fba_to__notifications'] or row['lsp_escalation_back_up'] or "no_address@rs-components.com"` line code is not working properly